# Paste data values - copied a sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that filters a table/range then copies the results and tries to create a new workbook and paste the data there (paste values & keep formating).

Also after it's done it tries to clear the filters from the source table.

**I can't make it paste the data in the new workbook from A1 (hedears included). It gets stuck and says "range not defined".** (it only pastes the formatting and gets stuck when trying to paste the values).

Also I'm new to vba but i have the feeling that the code starting from **Selection.Copy   ; Workbooks.Add** lines is basic/flauded and prone to errors.

Please help, this is the code:

```
Sub ExportRezAng()
'
' ExportRezAng Macro


    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As range
    Dim copyRange As range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("- - REZULTAT ANAF - -")


    ' turn off any autofilters that are already set
    src.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = src.range("D" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
    Set filterRange = src.range("A3:R" & lastRow)

    ' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
    ' in this case we are copying country from column A
    ' we set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
    Set copyRange = src.range("A3:N" & lastRow)

    ' filter range based on column B
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="DA", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=NU"

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    ' note that you can easily find the last populated row on this sheet
    ' if you don't want to over-write your previous results
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

**' FROM HERE THE PROBLEMS START !!!**

```
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


    Columns("M:N").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "CREDIT_DOSARE_EXECUTORI"

 ThisWorkbook. _
        Activate
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("- - REZULTAT ANAF - -").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't know which workbook or sheet you were refering to.

See this :

```
Sub ExportRezAng()
'
' ExportRezAng Macro
    Dim Src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wB As Workbook

    Set Src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("- - REZULTAT ANAF - -")

    ' turn off any autofilters that are already set
    Src.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = Src.Range("D" & Src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
    Set filterRange = Src.Range("A3:R" & lastRow)

    ' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
    ' in this case we are copying country from column A
    ' we set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
    Set copyRange = Src.Range("A3:N" & lastRow)

    ' filter range based on column B
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="DA", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=NU"

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    ' note that you can easily find the last populated row on this sheet
    ' if you don't want to over-write your previous results
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Set wB = Workbooks.Add
    With wB.Sheets(1)
        With .Range("A1")
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With '.Range("A1")
        .Columns("M:N").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Name = "CREDIT_DOSARE_EXECUTORI"
    End With 'wB.Sheets(1)

    Src.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Src.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: One last question please, if i want to copy two ranges at once ? as in: Set copyRange = Src.range("A3:H,O3:R" & lastRow)  - as in skipping certain columns from copy-paste how can i do it ?

Comment: @mistera : I don't know, generally I use the macro recorder and then customise the code! But pasting it will probably be quite a mess, so maybe do it in 2 copy/paste! ;)